# Testing private members of a class object returned by another class method using moq and xunit

Tags: c#, moq, xunit

I have a scenario like this:

```cs
public class A
{
    private int p1;

    public A(int x)
    {
        p1 = x;
    }
}

public class B
{
    public A Func1(int x)
    {
        if (x < 0)
        {
            return (new A(-1 * x));
        }
        else
        {
            return (new A(x));
        }
    }
}
```

I am wondering what are the options to test if `Func1` correctly sets the `p1` property of the returned object.

Thanks!

Comment: As things stand, you can't properly test that because `x` ends up being assigned to `A.p1`, which is `private`. That means you can't test whether the branch `x < 0` was taken or not - all you could do would be to verify that the returned `A` is not `null`.

Comment: @hagh You can't call `A`'s constructor because it is private. Please provide a code which compiles.

Comment: @PeterCsala: Thanks for pointing out. I modified the code. It should compile now.

Answer (score 1):

You always can reach a field via reflection:

```cs
[Fact]
public void TestMethod()
{
    A a = new B().Func1(-15);

    Assert.Equal(15,
        (int)a.GetType().GetField("p1", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).GetValue(a));
}
```

Comment: Yes, thanks to a teammate's suggestion we chose to do the same. In principle, I don't think this should be the first option though, but since I didn't want to touch the original code we chose to go with this approach. Thanks for the answer.